# Powershell IIS7 Snap in Assign SSL certificate to https binding

Tags: iis-7, powershell, web, ssl-certificate

As part of our automated build procedure we are trashing and reconstructing our IIS site with powershell scripts.

Once i have created the AppPool and the website complete with binding information I want to set the SSL certificate for the https binding. I can't find any concrete examples onl;ine anywhere that demonstrate this.

Any ideas?

Looking for a benevolent powershell god...

Comment: Were you able to solve this issue. I am able to create new binding but not able to associate SSL Certificate

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Here is how to do it simply:

First identify thecertificate that you want to assign and obtain it's thumbprint

e.g. Your certificate might be in cert:\LocalMachine\Root

You can obtain the thumbprint with the following:

```
$thumb = (Get-ChildItem cert:\LocalMachine\Root | where-object { $_.Subject -like "YOUR STRING HERE*" } | Select-Object -First 1).Thumbprint
```

<<< Now one can assign the certificate to an ip address and port comme ci >>>

```
$IPAddress = 101.100.1.90

$port = 443

Push-Location IIS:\SslBindings

Get-Item cert:\LocalMachine\Root\$thumb | New-Item $IPAddress!$port

Pop-Location
```

Hope this is of help to anyone

Answer (score 19):

You can merge previous examples with creation of an https binding in a web site.

```
import-module webadministration
$computerName = $Env:Computername
$domainName = $Env:UserDnsDomain
New-WebBinding -Name "MyWebSite" -IP "*" -Port 443 -Protocol https
Get-ChildItem cert:\LocalMachine\My | where { $_.Subject -match "CN\=$Computername\.$DomainName" } | select -First 1 | New-Item IIS:\SslBindings\0.0.0.0!443
```

Comment: Nice, an answer that makes sense and does what it says on the box. No offense to the other guys but this answer is complete and concise and I never have to know about thumbprints. :-)

Comment: This answer correctly refers to 'Personal' certificate storage under 'Local Computer', which is what IIS is using. Other answers refer to 'Trusted Root' storage instead.

Comment: Didnt understand the Get-ChildItem command how it knows which iis website to attach because we are not mentioning that anywhere.

Comment: I am keep getting error "New-Item : Cannot retrieve the dynamic parameters for the cmdlet. Failed to enumerate SSL 
bindings, error code 234."

Answer (score 2):

You can make the script simpler like this:

```
Get-ChildItem cert:\LocalMachine\Root | where { $_.Subject -like "YOUR STRING HERE*" } | select -First 1 | New-Item IIS:\SslBindings\0.0.0.0!443
```

Use 0.0.0.0 to target all hosted IP's (equivalent to "*" in IIS Manager) or replace it with a specific IP if needed.

Answer (score 0):

I've found an example here on how one can assign the certificate.

http://learn.iis.net/page.aspx/491/powershell-snap-in-configuring-ssl-with-the-iis-powershell-snap-in/

However, it doesn't seem very elegant having to hard code the certificate thumbprint
... so if any one knows of a better method, I'd be glad to hear.