# Powershell - Set SSL Certificate on https Binding

Tags: powershell, iis, ssl, certificate

I am trying to use PowerShell to set the SSL certificate on an IIS site for a self signed/local certificate.

I create the certificate:

```
$newCert = 
       New-SelfSignedCertificate 
       -DnsName www.mywebsite.ru 
       -CertStoreLocation cert:\LocalMachine\My
```

Then try to set the SSL bindings:

```
get-item 
      cert:\LocalMachine\MY\$newCert.Thumbprint | 
      new-item -path IIS:\SslBindings\0.0.0.0!443
```

as shown on this post: http://www.iis.net/learn/manage/powershell/powershell-snap-in-configuring-ssl-with-the-iis-powershell-snap-in

also shown here:
[Powershell IIS7 Snap in Assign SSL certificate to https binding](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2628970/powershell-iis7-snap-in-assign-ssl-certificate-to-https-binding)

I also tried:

```
get-item 
      cert:\LocalMachine\MY\$newCert.Thumbprint | 
      new-item -path IIS:\SslBindings\*!443
```

To no avail, I'm not seeing the SSL Certificate set in the Edit Site Binding dialog.

Any thoughts?

Comment: Use `IIS:\SslBindings\0.0.0.0!443` instead of `IIS:\SslBindings\*!443`. When you bind a site to this port, it will use the registered certificate.

Answer (score 56, accepted):

You have to assign the certifcate to a **specific** site.

You can retrieve the binding information of your site using the [Get-WebBinding](http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkID=268828) cmdlet and set the SSL Certificate using the `AddSslCertificate` function:

```
$siteName = 'mywebsite'
$dnsName = 'www.mywebsite.ru'

# create the ssl certificate
$newCert = New-SelfSignedCertificate -DnsName $dnsName -CertStoreLocation cert:\LocalMachine\My

# get the web binding of the site
$binding = Get-WebBinding -Name $siteName -Protocol "https"

# set the ssl certificate
$binding.AddSslCertificate($newCert.GetCertHashString(), "my")
```

Comment: At last line:  A specified logon session does not exist. It may already have been terminated. (Exception from HRESULT: 0x80070520)

Comment: @ChuckD That usually means that your private key is either missing or cannot be accessed by the user IIS is running as.

Edit: Or yeah, it hasn't been imported like Richard Squires said. :D

Answer (score 3):

I had the same error as "Chuck D" when using the answer, I found an additional step was required:

The SSL certificate needs to be in the certificate store before binding to adding to an IIS website binding. This can be done in powershell using the following command:

```
Import-PfxCertificate -FilePath "C:\path to certificate file\certificate.pfx" -CertStoreLocation "Cert:\LocalMachine\My"
```

Answer (score 1):

The AddSslCertificate method not available everywhere. I found different solution by using Netsh.

```
$iisCert = Get-ChildItem -Path "Cert:\LocalMachine\MY" `
| Where-Object { $_.FriendlyName -eq "IIS Express Development Certificate" } `
| Select-Object -First 1

$applicationId = [Guid]::NewGuid().ToString("B") 

netsh http add sslcert ipport=0.0.0.0:443 certhash=$($iisCert.Thumbprint) appid=$applicationId
```

It is possible to set other parameters as well (e.g. `certstorename=MY`). More information can be found on [HTTP Server API](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/http/add-sslcert) page.