# How can i select the newly installed SSL Certificate for the website bindings

Tags: powershell

i am using cert util commands to add the ssl certificate but after adding the certificate how can i select the new one using the power shell for all the website hosted

i tried below powershell to select the newly installed certificate but i am getting error SSL Certificate add failed, Error: 183
Cannot create a file when that file already exists.
sometimes , SSL Certificate add failed, Error: 1312
A specified logon session does not exist. It may already have been terminated

```
$hostname="*.domain.net"
$cert = (Get-ChildItem cert:\LocalMachine\My | where-object { $_.Subject -like "*$hostname*" } | Select-Object -First 1).Thumbprint
$guid = [guid]::NewGuid().ToString("B")
netsh http add sslcert ipport="${IPAddressV2}:443" certhash=$cert certstorename=MY appid="$guid"
netsh http add sslcert ipport="${IPAddressV3}:443" certhash=$cert certstorename=MY appid="$guid"
netsh http add sslcert ipport="127.0.0.1:443" certhash=$cert certstorename=MY appid="$guid"
```

Comment: My IIS/http.sys knowledge is a bit rusty, but I'm pretty sure that means a cert is already bound to that `ipport` combination

Comment: but ,when i check the binding status, still the SSL Certificate shows not selected. then i have to click on the drop down and select the certificate manually.some times i am getting error:1312

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is the working script which automatically  select the newly installed certificate for all the bindings with the port number 443

```
Import-Module Webadministration
    IIS:
    $IPAddress = "C:\Ipaddress.txt"
    $Bindings = Get-WebBinding | Where-Object {$_.protocol -eq "https"} | Select-Object -ExpandProperty bindingInformation 
    $IPs = $Bindings | ForEach-Object { @($_ -split ':')[0]}
    $IPs = @($IPs |Sort-Object -Unique) > $IPAddress

    Import-Module Webadministration
    $Friendlyname="*.abcd.com"
    Get-ChildItem cert:\LocalMachine\My | where-object { $_.Subject -like "*$Friendlyname*" }
    $hostname = Get-Content C:\Ipaddress.txt 
    foreach ($name in $hostname) { 
    $cert = (Get-ChildItem cert:\LocalMachine\My | where-object { $_.Subject -like "*$Friendlyname*" } | Select-Object -First 1).Thumbprint
    Remove-Item -path "IIS:\SslBindings\${name}!443"
    TIMEOUT /T 5 /NOBREAK
    New-Item -path "IIS:\SslBindings\$name!443" -Thumbprint $cert}
```

Comment: this worked for me, to add the SSL cert to all my https site. Thanks

Answer (score 1):

You are trying to bind an SSL cert to a wild card hostname.
SSL Certs are one per website, though that SSL cert can be a wildcard, the site should be a unique name.

As further discussed here...

> https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/iis/manage/powershell/powershell-snap-in-configuring-ssl-with-the-iis-powershell-snap-in

.. and in this post /answer.

> [Powershell - Set SSL Certificate on https Binding](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32390097/powershell-set-ssl-certificate-on-https-binding)

***Update as per OP request***

Assuming this is IIS. It's best to import the WebAdministration module as well, to have all the IIS cmdlets and IIS PSDrive at hand.

```
# Set SSL bindings for the default site, as an example
New-WebBinding -Name "Default Web Site" -Protocol "https" -IPAddress "10.10.0.3" -Port 443 -HostHeader "intranet.corp.contoso.com"

$SSLCert = Get-ChildItem –Path "cert:\LocalMachine\My" | 
Where-Object {$_.subject -like 'cn=intranet*'}

New-Item "IIS:SslBindings\10.10.0.3!443" -value $SSLCert
```

Here is the primary IIS article to leverage from the IIS folks. There are many cases in the article, I've snipped the pertinent ones that should get you where you need to go.

> IIS Powershell User guide - Comparing representative IIS UI tasks
>   https://blogs.iis.net/jeonghwan/iis-powershell-user-guide-comparing-representative-iis-ui-tasks

```
# Related UI Task:"Add Web Site..." wizard

# 18.[Sites] Set bindings 
Case1: Create SSL Binding (127.0.0.1!443)
$certObect=get-item cert:LocalMachineMyE48803C3A6DDC8F2BFE3D8B7B7D56BBA70270F92new-item IIS:SslBindings127.0.0.1!443 -value $certObect

# Case2: Set 'Bindings' property with multiple binding information including the SSL binding which was created above.
$newBinding=(@{protocol="http";bindingInformation="127.0.0.1:80:normalSite"},@{protocol="https";bindingInformation="127.0.0.1:443:securedSite"})
Set-itemproperty "IIS:SitesDefault Web Site" -name bindings -value $newBinding


# Or, you can use other task-based  cmdlet(s) instead:
New-WebBinding -Site "Default Web Site" -Port 443 -IPAddress 127.0.0.1 -HostHeader securedSite


# NOTE: you can also use set-webconfiguration, set-webconfiguration or add-webconfigurationProperty.
Set-Webconfiguration '/system.applicationHost/sites/site[@name="Default Web Site"]/bindings' -value $newBinding  -PSPath iis:
Set-WebconfigurationProperty '/system.applicationHost/sites/site[@name="Default Web Site"]' -name bindings.collection -value $newBinding -at 0  -PSPath iis:
Add-WebconfigurationProperty '/system.applicationHost/sites/site[@name="Default Web Site"]' -name bindings.collection -value @{protocol="https";bindingInformation="127.0.0.1:443:securedSite"} -at 0  -PSPath iis:
```

Comment: i have the certificate already created and imported using the certutil, now i want to select that certificate to sites binding? so how can i by pass the certificate creation? also i am getting the error**( Method invocation failed because [System.Object[]] doesn't contain a method named 'GetCertHashString'.)**

Comment: Those articles include all the steps, you just use the ones that are pertinent to your needs. You only need the unique cert name to bind to the site. See my update for you.

Comment: when i use the cmdlets above i am getting the error, New-Item : A specified logon session does not exist. It may already have been terminated. this is coming if i try to select using GUI as well. what can we do for this error.

Comment: also getting this error, also this error Cannot retrieve the dynamic parameters for the cmdlet. Failed to enumerate SSL bindings, error code 234.