# How to add created certificate to an IIS https binding using PowerShell

Tags: powershell, iis, ssl-certificate

I can create a self signed certificate with PowerShell:

```
$cert = New-SelfSignedCertificate –DnsName www.test.com -CertStoreLocation “cert:\LocalMachine\My”
```

I also can create bindings for my site:

```
New-WebBinding -Name "Test" -IPAddress "*" -Protocol "https" -Port 443 -HostHeader www.test.com -SslFlags 1
```

However based on the documentation New-WebBinding has no parameter which accepts a certificate [see: New-WebBinding documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/webadminstration/new-webbinding?view=winserver2012-ps)

**Question**

How can I properly create the https binding which is using the created certificate?

Answer (score 1):

From [this related question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51921743/how-can-i-select-the-newly-installed-ssl-certificate-for-the-website-bindings/51923799#51923799). Replace 127.0.0.1 with your IP address:

```
Import-Module Webadministration
$IPAddress = '127.0.0.1' #your IIS server IP address
New-WebBinding -Name "Default Web Site" -Protocol "https" -IPAddress $IPAddress -Port 443 -HostHeader "www.test.com"
$SSLCert = Get-ChildItem –Path "cert:\LocalMachine\My" | 
  Where-Object {$_.subject -like 'cn=www.test.com*'}
New-Item "IIS:SslBindings\$IPAddress!443" -value $SSLCert
```